# Holiday Booking system, search for date - return a list of employees who are on holiday on that date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I seem to be asking a lot of questions on here recently, thanks in advance for any help!

First - I have a calendar table which may make this easier. Calendar table is pretty standard, a dateID, Date and varying different formats of that date.

I want to give the query a date, and for it to return a list of all employees and whether or not they were on holiday on that date.

[image: Employee Table]
[image: Leave Table]

LeaveTypeID is 1 for holiday 2 for sickness, 3 for compassionate, etc, etc, I'm only concerned with holiday at this point.
StartDate and EndDate are as they appear
StartMidday is whether or not the holiday starts at midday on the first day (so working the morning and starting the holiday at lunch), same for endmidday but for the end of the holiday period)

Would ideally like it to say whether that day is a half day as well if possible?
So I want my result to be something like (assuming I chose the date of the 4th Nov, 2016)

```
EmployeeID  OnHoliday   IsHalf
1             TRUE       TRUE
2             FALSE      FALSE
3             FALSE      FALSE
4             FALSE      FALSE
5             FALSE      FALSE
```

Hopefully that's enough info. Thanks again in advance!

Comment: What is the logic of `[IsHalf]` ?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @TedoG. Sorry, it doesn't line up with the screenshots of tables.
a holiday lasting 3 days where the first day is a half day - the first day would show true, true, the other 2 days would show true, false

Comment: @jarlh to be honest, I'm not sure where to start. Elsewhere in the project I have something that lists all the days for a specific holiday for a specific employee, for the purpose of calculating number of days of holiday allowance that holiday has taken up. But not really sure where to start here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can use between for this purpose:

```
    declare @InputDate date='2016-09-16' --yur input date

   select EmployeeId,
   case when (select count(1) from EmployeeLeave 
   where (@InputDate between StartDate and EndDate) 
   and EmployeeLeave .EmployeeId=Employee .EmployeeId)>1 then 'True' else 'False' end as [OnHoliday],
   case when ((select StartMidDay from EmployeeLeave 
   where (@InputDate between StartDate and EndDate) 
   and EmployeeLeave .EmployeeId=Employee .EmployeeId))=0.5 then 'True' else 'False' end as [IsHalf] ,
   from Employee
```

Comment: I can't get this working 

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Had an extra comma before the From Employee on the last line but after taking that it works like a dream.

Answers my original question perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have come up with a solution by myself

```
declare @DateAdd int=0 --add Days From Monday
declare @LeaveType int=1 -- Leave Type

declare @SelctedDate date = DATEADD(DD, @DateAdd, CAST('2016-11-21' AS DATE)) --Week Commencing

select 
      (CASE 
            WHEN (leaveTemp.StartMidday = '0.5' AND leaveTemp.StartDate = @SelctedDate) THEN '4:00'
            WHEN (leaveTemp.EndMidday = '0.5' AND leaveTemp.EndDate = @SelctedDate)  THEN '4:00'
            WHEN LeaveID is not null THEN '8:00'
            ELSE NULL
      END ) as HolMon

from Employee left join
(select employeeID, LeaveID, StartDate, EndDate, StartMidday, EndMidday
      from EmployeeLeave
      where LeaveTypeID=@LeaveType and @SelctedDate between startdate and enddate
) as leaveTemp
on Employee.EmployeeID = leaveTemp.EmployeeID
ORDER BY Employee.EmployeeForename, Employee.EmployeeID
```

This seems to bring back what I was after but is the best way to do it?

Comment: Would it be possible to combine the other fields in this query to a single column?
Instead of 
select employeeID, LeaveID, enddate, StartMidday, EndMidday

Could it be
select employeeID, [if startmidday or endmidday = 0.5 then half else if leaveID is not null then full else null]

Comment: This will work though it will give you multiple rows if an employee happens to have multiple leave records at the same time. These type of problems are made a lot easier if you are able to create a row for each day that someone is on leave and then you just query on one date column.